# What are some non-RL-based approaches to solving a typical bin assignment problem?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reference-request, classification, algorithm-request

What are some non-RL-based approaches to solving a typical bin assignment problem, i.e., given a set of items (can be multidimensional), find the bin/knapsack/target which best packs (with minimum wastage of space) the items?

I tried looking for some papers on this but most of them are RL-based methods or haven't described the approach lucidly, hence am reaching out to the community. Any help in this would be greatly appreciated